# Best way to provide object attributes?

Tags: python

I have a base class and  I need to create 70 objects of this class. The base class has 6 attributes and these need to be set for the objects as well.

Since I know the values for every attribute for every object, what would be the best way to feed them in. I can think of 2 ways.

1- Crate a python file where I create these 70 objects and set attributes for each of them. This cause a lot of duplication in the code and will also make changing the values a bit complicated.

2- I can stores all of them in a text file. Read them row by row, and then in a loop create a new object every time,and set its attributes to the values read in this iteration. This would keep my assignment code concise and would also keep the attributes values encapsulated in a text file.

I prefer the second one, any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: If it works for your application then go ahead.

Comment: With any choice, you will have 70 times 6 values in a file. Why would you want to use your own file format to keep values of your attributes, in addition to some code to read, interpret and validate it? Python source file format is already standardized, and on top of that it's validated and interpreted by the Python compiler!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the class has a constructor to which you provide the attributes you could simply create the objects using that.

Anyway you have to place the objects somewhere too. If you're going to put them in a container of some kind you could write it more compactly by using a list or similar:

```
attribute_list = [ ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                  (11,12,13,14,15,16),
                   # and so on
         ]

for attrs in attribute_list:
    container.append( TheClass( *attrs ) )
```

If you don't put the objects in a container or similar there's little hope in making it more compact, you basically have to resort to:

```
obj1 = TheClass( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 )
obj2 = TheClass( 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 )
# etc
```